# File upload in google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, file-upload, google-forms

In google sheets script we write function which dynamically change the google form like

if we want to add name field in google form then we write in google sheet script:

`form.addTextItem().setTitle(NAME);`

My question is that in google form, is there an option for file upload (file upload those who fill the form) so which function is used to set file upload(Add file) in google sheet script ?

---

For short answer- `form.addTextItem();`
For file upload- ??

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59400692/how-to-import-file-upload-module-in-google-form-using-google-apps-script) is related.

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunately it is not possible

Several users already filed a feature request on Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com), but so far it has not been implemented.

Have a look e.g. et [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/64924665) and give it a "star" - the more people ask for the feature to be implemented, ther more likely it is that Google is going to do it.